# Why Moq is throwing "expected Invocation on the mock at least once". Where as it is being set once,even though it is being set to null?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Following is the code. create a class lib add the ref to NUnit framework 2.5.3.9345 and Moq.dll 4.0.0.0 and paste the following code. Try running it on my machine it throws

> TestCase
>   'MoqTest.TryClassTest.IsMessageNotNull'
>   failed: Moq.MockException :  Expected
>   invocation on the mock at least once,
>   but was never performed: v => v.Model
>   = It.Is(value(Moq.It+<>c__DisplayClass2`1[MoqTest.GenInfo]).match)
>
>    at
>
>   Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(IProxyCall
>
>   expected, Expression expression, Times
>
>   times, Int32 callCount)  at
>
>   Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor
>
>   targetInterceptor, MethodCall
>
>   expected, Expression expression, Times
>
>   times)  at
>
>   Moq.Mock.VerifySet[T](Mock`1 mock,
>   Action`1 setterExpression, Times
>
>   times, String failMessage)  at
>
>   Moq.Mock`1.VerifySet(Action`1
>   setterExpression)  Class1.cs(22,0): at
>   MoqTest.TryClassTest.IsMessageNotNull()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MoqTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TryClassTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void IsMessageNotNull()
        {
            var mockView = new Mock<IView<GenInfo>>();
            mockView.Setup(v => v.ModuleId).Returns("");

            TryPresenter tryPresenter = new TryPresenter(mockView.Object);
            tryPresenter.SetMessage(new object(), new EventArgs());
            // mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Message, Times.AtLeastOnce());
            mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model = It.Is<GenInfo>(x => x != null));
        }
    }

    public class TryPresenter
    {
        private IView<GenInfo> view;
        public TryPresenter(IView<GenInfo> view)
        {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void SetMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.view.Model = null;
        }
    }

    public class MyView : IView<GenInfo>
    {
        #region Implementation of IView<GenInfo>

        public string ModuleId
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public GenInfo Model
        {
            get; set;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public interface IView<T>
    {
        string ModuleId { get; set; }
        T Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenInfo
    {
        public String Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And if you change one line

```
mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model = It.Is<GenInfo>(x => x != null));
```

to

```
mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model, Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

it works fine.

I think Exception is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the following VerifySet assertion:

```
mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model = It.Is<GenInfo>(x => x != null));
```

which basically says "verify that I Set the Model property with some GenInfo object that's not null".

Then, you set the Model property with a null object:

```
this.view.Model = null;
```

Of course the assertion fails.

In your second VerifySet assertion

```
mockView.VerifySet(v => v.Model, Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

you are saying "assert that the Model property was Set, *with anything*, at least once". Since you did Set it (albeit with a null), of course the assertion passes.

I don't think there's any error in Moq's behavior here.